# How to solve this complicated ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following non-linear ODE:

$$x^2  \frac{dy}{dx} + \exp{\left(x \, \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} \right)} = \sin \left(\frac{d^3y}{dx^3} \, \cos \left( \frac{d^4y}{dx^4} \right) \right) $$

I have no idea where to even begin. Could someone show me how to solve it or at the very least give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: I would be amazed if this had an analytic solution. Where did you come across it?

Comment: Numerical solution has a way out  from this rather implicit and inverse relation.